# Find $\sup\left\{x_n\right\}$ and $\inf\left\{x_n\right\}$ where $x_n= (-1)^n+\cos\frac{n\pi}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $\left\{x_n\right\}$ be a sequence such that $x_n= (-1)^n+\cos\frac{n\pi}{4}$. Find $\sup\left\{x_n\right\}$ and $\inf\left\{x_n\right\}$.

$(-1)^n=-1$ (when $n$ is odd), $1$(when $n$ is even).

$\cos\frac{n\pi}{4}= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ or $-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$(when $n$ is odd), $0, 1$ or $-1$(when $n$ is even).

So, from the values, I can directly write $\sup\left\{x_n\right\}=2$ and $\inf\left\{x_n\right\}=-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

But I want to know, does the sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$ converge? If yes, to which point does it converge?

Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you write out the first 10 elements of this sequence for me?

Comment: @StanTendijck $\left\{-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 1, -1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 0, -1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 1, -1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 2, -1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 1,....\right\}$

Comment: I can't see whether the answer was posted before your answer to my comment. I hope that you found out by yourself that just writing out some terms of the sequence you start seeing a pattern. And then from there, you can draw your conclusions ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence does not converge. Note that $x_{n+8} = x_n$, and so the sequence is periodic, but it takes at least two distinct values, so it can never converge to a single value.